# Import Issue With django.views

Tags: python, django, vue.js, import, pycharm

I'm working with a small team to create a python project with Django and Vue implemented. We're having troubles with our import statements and having PyCharm recognize the file path.

```
from django.views import views as vue_views
```

This particular line of code is what's causing the problem. Pycharm keeps telling us "Cannot find reference 'views' in '**init**.py' ".
When we run the django server, the console will tell us "ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'django.views' (C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\views_*init*_.py)".

This is the 'urls.py' file that we are using:

```
from django import views as vue_views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

# from DB_Vue_Project import views as vue_views


urlpatterns = [
    # the below path leads to admin
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapi.urls')),
    path('admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    # have to type /test
    path('test', vue_views.test_vue),

]
```

The project will work fine on one of my coworkers machines but gives us these errors when any of us pull it from git. This leads us to believe it has something to do with our interpreter or something like that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What views module you expect to import from here: https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/views ? :)

Comment: There is no `views` in `django.views`. You likely want to `from django import views as vue_views`.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, name your project `django`? Please do *not* do this.

Comment: The project name is "DB_django_Project". I've updated the post to show the urls.py file. When changing the import line to `from django import views as vue_views`, the last line in the `urlpatterns` list tells us `Cannot find reference 'test_vue' in '__init__.py'` and the terminal gives us an `AttributeError: module 'django.views' has no attribute 'test_vue'` error.

Comment: But your `vue_views` are from *that app*, so `from DB_Vue_Project import views as vue_views`, not `from django import views as view`.

Comment: Furthermore normally modules are written in (lowercase) snake case, so `db_vue_project`: see the PEP8 style guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the stylizing tips! We're totally new to this so, it's appreciated. I changed the line to `from DB_Vue_Project import views as vue_views` and the in-code errors are gone, but when running the server, the terminal tells us `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DB_django_Project.models'`.

Comment: If it would help, I can absolutely send some data about the file structure of our project or any interpreter settings details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding a views.py file in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\views. In the file was this code:

```html
from django.shortcuts import render

def test_vue(request):
    return render(request, 'DB_Vue_Project/test.html')
```